Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a(a-1)\dots(a-n+1)}{n!}$
Does the following sum converge?
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a(a-1)\dots(a-n+1)}{n!}$ where $a \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{N}$
If the series had positive terms, it would be convergent by the ratio test in the following way: $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a(a-1)\dots(a-n)}{(n+1)!}\frac{n!}{a(a-1)\dots(a-n+1)}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a-n}{n+1}=-1<1 \implies$ the sum is convergent, but $a \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{N}$ and I don't know what can I do to examine the absolute convergence and the convergence.

https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1576809/42969

We have not learned about the gamma function at university, so it should be solved without using it.

The product in the numerator can be recognized as a falling factorial.
